# On odd perfect numbers $q^k n^2$ satisfying $n^2 - q^k = 2^r t$

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, satisfying
$$n^2 - q^k = 2^r t$$
where $r \geq 2$ and $\gcd(2,t)=1$.

We could prove that:

> **(1)** $2^r t > 2n$.  (We can modestly improve this to
> $$2^r t > \frac{3373n^2}{3375},$$ since per [this answer to a related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4028814/28816), we have the lower bound $\sigma(n^2)/q^k \geq {3^3} \times {5^3} = 3375$, which implies that
> $$q^k < \frac{2n^2}{3375}.)$$

> **(2)** $n^2 - q^k$ is not a square.

Our question is:

> **Must it necessarily be the case that $n > \max(2^r, t)$?**

That is, can we rule out the following cases?

> **(A)** $t > n > 2^r$

> **(B)** $2^r > n > t$

Comment: I think that, without further constraints, you can not rule out the cases you state, as all the conditions stated can be satisfied in each of those cases

Comment: Would you mind sharing more details about your thoughts on this problem @JuanMoreno, by posting an answer?

Answer (score 2):

It is asked if necessarily $n>\max(2^r,t)$, providing certain constraints. This constraints can be satisfied if $n<\max(2^r,t)$, so further constraints are needed.

For instance, consider $n=675$, $q=13$, $k=5$, $r=2$, $t=21083$. All the constraints are satisfied (excepting $N$ being some odd perfect number, which if satisfied would be a breakthrough discovery), but $t>n>2^r$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am actually interested in proving $n < q^k$ (and therefore, ruling out $q^k < n$) generally from the constraint
$$n^2 - q^k = 2^r t$$
where $r \geq 2$ and $\gcd(2, t)=1$, @JuanMoreno.

Comment: Your supposed example for $t > n > 2^r$ actually contradicts the following requirement for the factor $n$, which is implied by the following estimates:  **(1)** $q^k < n^2$ [(Dris, 2012)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html); and **(2)** $N = q^k n^2 > {10}^{1500}$ [(Ochem and Rao, 2012)](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2012-81-279/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4.pdf).  These two estimates imply $n > {10}^{375}$.

Comment: Anyway, I will be interested in seeing a (specific) example where $q^k < n$, even if it is not true that $n > {10}^{375}$.  (Of course!)

Comment: That is, I seek (specific) examples for the conditions $t > n > 2^r$ or $2^r > n > t$, which satisfies the constraint $q^k < n$.

Comment: I got the following example from this [answer to a closely related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555053):

$$n = 9, q = 5, k = 1, r = 2, t = 19$$

$$t > n > 2^r$$

It **does seem to be the situation** that $t > n > 2^r$ is the *problematic case*.

Comment: I have unaccepted your answer, @JuanMoreno, in view of some recent findings pointing to the possibility that $t=1$.  (Please refer to this [answer1](https://mathoverflow.net/a/405222/10365) and [answer2](https://mathoverflow.net/a/405229/10365).)

Comment: It seems that your proof of $t=1$ is flawed, as pointed out by @mathlove

Comment: Let me work it out for the next couple of weeks, @JuanMoreno.